# OpenLayers 5, Angular 7 lines not showing

Tags: angular, openlayers

I am using `Angular 7`, `OpenLayers 5` to show map with markers. Now I want to draw lines between markers. I followed some examples. Like [this](https://nikokiuru.com/2012/12/how-to-draw-lines-with-openlayers/).

But the lines don't show up. I tried to pass array of coordinates to `LineString` instead of `Point`. That didn't work either. I'd appreciate some help.

Here's the code:

```
   this.source = new XYZ({
     url: 'http://tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
   });

   this.layer = new TileLayer({
     source: this.source
   });

   this.view = new View({
     center: fromLonLat([lon, lat]),
     zoom: 5
   });

   this.map = new Map({
     target: 'map',
     layers: [this.layer],
     view: this.view,
     controls: defaultControls().extend([
       new OverviewMap()
     ]),
   });

   let vectorSource = new VectorSource({});

    // create features for markers
    for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
      let nodeFeature = new Feature({
        geometry: new Point(fromLonLat([nodes[i].lon, nodes[i].lat])),
        name: nodes[i].name
      });
      vectorSource.addFeature(nodeFeature);
    }
    let vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
      source: vectorSource
    });
    this.map.addLayer(vectorLayer);

   const fromProjection = new Projection("EPSG:4326");   // Transform from WGS 1984
   const toProjection = new Projection("EPSG:900913");

   let lon = 24.9342;
   let lat = 60.2017;

   // Start and end point
   let start_point1 = new Point(lon, lat).transform(fromProjection, toProjection);
   let end_point1 = new Point(30.9342, 62.2017).transform(fromProjection, toProjection);

   let start_point2 = new Point(lon, lat).transform(fromProjection, toProjection);
   let end_point2 = new Point(20.9342, 55.2017).transform(fromProjection, toProjection);

   // new vector graphic layer
   var layerLines = new LayerVector({
     source: new VectorSource({
         features: [new Feature({
             geometry: new LineString([start_point1, end_point1]),
             name: 'Line 1'
         }), 
         new Feature({
           geometry: new LineString([start_point2, end_point2]),
           name: 'Line 2'
       })]
     })
 });
   this.map.addLayer(layerLines);
```

Comment: How are you displaying markers (that appear on the map)?  The [link](https://nikokiuru.com/2012/12/how-to-draw-lines-with-openlayers/) you reference is OpenLayers v2, which is very different from v5.

Comment: I'm new to `OpenLayers'. On their example site, there's [this one](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/line-arrows.html). But in my case, the links are static.

Comment: Updated the code with markers display.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with markers and lines. I'm new to `OpenLayers` and still learning. There are probably better examples but these two that I found, make better sense to me:

1. [how to add lines between point in openlayers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52241140/how-to-add-lines-between-point-in-openlayers)
2. [Marker Animation](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/feature-move-animation.html)

The first example shows how to transform projections for `LineString` then add to `Feature`. The second one shows how to use different styles. In my case, I have different styles for the lines and markers.